# ¿Cómo obtener coordenadas sobre una imagen en un evento OnMouseMove?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy usando Vuejs. Quiero obtener las coordenadas de una imagen en un evento `OnMouseMove`.

Para obtener las coordenadas exactas por donde vaya pasando el cursor mientras mantengo el mouse presionado.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    captureToggle: false,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  methods: {
    mo: function(evt) {
      if (this.captureToggle) {
        this.x = evt.x
        this.y = evt.y
      }
    },
    captureOn: function() {
      this.captureToggle = true
    },
    captureOff: function() {
      this.captureToggle = false
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  margin: 50px;
}

img {
 pointer-events:none;
  width: 600px;
  border: solid thin;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="mouseArea" @mousedown="captureOn" @mouseup="captureOff" @mousemove="mo">
    <img src="https://jcastillovnz.github.io/Carque-360/iframes/roof/img/roof/renders/0.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>x : {{x}}</div>
  <div>y : {{y}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola. Cuando haces referencia a _las coordenadas de una imagen_ ¿a qué te refieres? ¿Quieres saber la posición del mouse con respecto a la esquina superior izquierda de la imagen o quieres saber las coordenadas del evento con respecto a la página?

Answer (score -2):

Usa `pageX` y `pageY` en lugar de `x` e `y`:

```
mo: function(evt) {
  if (this.captureToggle) {
    this.x = evt.pageX
    this.y = evt.pageY
  }
}
```

Comment: Hole James. Bienvenido a SOes. Como estás en la versión de SO en español, las respuestas debes darlas en este idioma. Por otro lado, sería bueno que añadieras a tu respuesta por qué crees que debe hacer ese cambio, cuáles son las diferencias entre las propiedades, etc.  Pásate por [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)